# GitLab on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I got on wednesday my new Raspberry Pi Model B and I tried to install GitLab with the wikis.

- [GitLab - Installation from source](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)
- [Debian Squeeze complete Installation 'script' with RVM](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Debian-Squeeze-complete-Installation-%27script%27-with-RVM)

The installation went perfectly until I ran:

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres
```

After that I waited a long time but nothing happens apart from the output:

```
# Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
```

During the process "bundle" runs, the CPU has a usage of over 90% and the RES value grows endlessly.
I googled much hours and found some topics but nothing worked. (I reinstalled already Raspbian once, because I did not know what to do after ruined everything.)

What should I do now to go on with the installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [this forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=32716&p=425036), here is a modified instruction set from that forum post:

> 1. Follow instructions [from this installation guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) until step 6.
> 2. In a separate directory install [libv8](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8).  Use the newest version, because most issues with libv8 is due to old code not able to
>    be compiled on ARM systems.  [It isn't possible to install it from
>    Gem](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/257).
> 3. Continue to follow [step 6](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#6-gitlab) till the [installation step for Gems](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#install-gems).
> 4. [Add missing config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3639) in `/home/git/gitlab`.  Run:
>
>    ```
>     $ sudo -u git cp config/puma.rb.example config/puma.rb
>    ```
> 5. Edit `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in `/home/git/gitlab` directory [to a clean version of libv8 and therubyracer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/download/file.php?id=4232).
> 6. [Install `node.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059332/could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime-see-https-github-com-sstephenson-execjs-f):
>
>    ```
>     $ sudo apt-get install nodejs
>    ```
> 7. [Continue to install Gems](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#install-gems).

It should be ready after that.  The first time you access the page it will take a long time to respond (around 15 minutes!).  After that the time will be reduced to around 5 seconds for a page.

Comment: at this step < $ sudo -u git cp config/puma.rb.example config/puma.rb > i've got this error : no such file or directory. Can anyone tell me where's the problem ? thx